# how to specify the frequency resolution in cpsd function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

To use cpsd function in Matlab I can specify the frequencies for which I want the power spectral to be calculated (f = [25:90]). But the frequency resolution should be calculated based on the segment length. Therefore I am not sure how the frequency band should be specified.
for example for a data with 200 Hz sampling rate is it correct to find pxy as follow:

```
    window = 2000;
    noverlap = 1000;
    f = [25:0.1:90];
    fs = 200;
    [pxy,f] = cpsd(x,y,window,noverlap,f,fs);
```

Thanks